# Why do you need to pass a variable as a parameter for function instead of just using it?

Tags: python

If functions can get values of variables from outside, why do we need to pass the variables as parameters then?

```
>>> a = 1234

>>> def fun1():
        return a + 1 
>>> fun1()
1235
```

We can change the variable and just return its new value, what's the advantage of passing it as a parameter?

Comment: Because global variables are *unsafe*. You usually want to scope.

Comment: what if I want to add a different value of `a` or what if I want to reuse this function?

Comment: Furthermore if you do multithreading, then the variable can change all of a sudden.

Comment: Finally functions in Python are first class citizens: you can pass functions as blackboxes, so you don't know on which (global) variables they depend.

Comment: Ahh, okay, it's clearer now. Thanks guys